# RSpec 1.x to RSpec 2.x (Rails 2.x to Rails 3.x)

Tags: rspec, rails-3-upgrade

I am in the process of converting a Rails 2.x application to Rails 3.x.  The Rails 2.x project's specs execute with all passing currently.

However after moving the specs to the Rails 3.x application the specs die, unable to find a base class (`SmsCommand::Base`) defined in the `Rails.root + '/lib'` directory.  I have tried running the specs with just `rspec path_to_spec`, `rake spec` and `bundle exec rspec path_to_spec` all to no avail.

I am concerned that it may have to do with directory nesting.  As an example:

```
/spec/models/sms_commands/accept_spec.rb
```

is the spec for:

```
/app/models/sms_commands/accept.rb
```

The `Accept` class inherits from `SmsCommand::Base` which is contained at:

```
/lib/sms_command.rb
```

It seems as though the Rails autoloader isn't happening for specs or its just not autoloading the /lib directory at all.

The output from `rake spec` is:

```
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@a_project/gems/rspec-core 2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:
in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Object::SmsCommand (NameError)
from /Users/xxx/Projects/a_project/app/models/sms_commands/accept.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

My `spec_helper` which is required by each spec has the following pertinent lines: (I have tried to force the issue with the manual `require` for each `*.rb` in the `lib` directory.)

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
Dir[File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..', 'lib','**','*.rb'))].each {|f| require f}
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','config','environment'))
#require 'spec/autorun'
require 'spec/rails'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading this:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218-rails-3-rc-does-not-autoload-from-lib

... it turns out that `/lib` isn't autoloaded by default and there's really no warning in the `application.rb` for whatever reason.

Adding

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

in my `Application` fixed the problem.